# How to Mock EF Entity with "Include" method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking

My repository layer method returns "abc" object in the following way

```
return this.context.abc.Include(x => x.xyz);
```

the return type is `abc`

i want to mock this object so that it includes `xyz` as well.

```
private MockDbSet<abc> MockAbc()
{
    return new MockDbSet<abc>
    {
        Builder<abc>.CreateNew().Build(), 
        Builder<abc>.CreateNew().Build(), 
        Builder<abc>.CreateNew().Build(), 
        Builder<abc>.CreateNew().Build(),
    };
}
```

How can i include `xyz` while mocking it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mock entity framework is not very easy,have you looked into some tool like [Effort](http://effort.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tutorials&referringTitle=Home) ?.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you're looking for but Entity Framework is no joke to mock and you'll always end up with a "leaky abstraction". Don't do it.

I think your EF queries should be wrapped in an IService layer where the **output** can be mocked.